# Problem with simple form in Spring Jsp used

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have made some magic from ->>> https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-form-tutorial

And I don't have any idea why, but the code does not work.

I tried to change catalogs, names, added weird in properties, but everything failed.

```
spring.view.prefix= /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.view.suffix= .jsp
```

### Forms.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form:form method="POST"
          action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addFlightDTO" modelAttribute="FlightDTO">
             <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="DateFrom">DateFrom</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="DateFrom"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="DateTo">DateTo</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="DateTo"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="Origin">Origin</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="Origin"/></td>
                </tr>

                  <tr>
                     <td><form:label path="Departure">Departure</form:label></td>
                     <td><form:input path="Departure"/></td>
                   </tr>


                   <tr>
                     <td><form:label path="currency">currency</form:label></td>
                     <td><form:input path="currency"/></td>
                   </tr>





                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
public class FlightDTO {
    private String DateFrom;
    private String DateTo;
    private String Origin;
    private String Departure;
    private Double currency;
getters, setters ...
```

---

```
@Controller
public class FormController {



        @RequestMapping(value = "/FlightDTO", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView showForm() {
            return new ModelAndView("Forms", "FlightDTO", new FlightDTO());
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/addFlightDTO", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String submit(@Valid @ModelAttribute("FlightDTO")FlightDTO flightDTO,
                             BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return "error.jsp";
            }
            model.addAttribute("DateFrom", flightDTO.getDateFrom());
            model.addAttribute("DateTo", flightDTO.getDateTo());
            model.addAttribute("currency", flightDTO.getCurrency());
            return "Results";
        }
    }
```

---

Error message

```
THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-5] Exception processing template "Forms": Error resolving template [jsp/Forms], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [Forms], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
```

==============================================

I tried different solutions. I do not see any difference between my code and the code in the guide.

To run the form, I use these two links:

http: // localhost: 8080 / FlightDTO
http: // localhost: 8080 / flight-radar / FlightDTO

Please help :)

Comment: What directory is Forms.jsp in ?   Also : do you want to use Spring MVC (from the Baeldung article) or Thymeleaf (from your exception) ? (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41019274/difference-between-spring-jsp-mvc-and-thymeleaf-mvc )

Comment: Hi Nisse ! Thank You very much for Your help! U have opened my eyes. I made example from https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/ and it's works. But still I dont have idea why previous example did not work properly.